# How to escape dot in python str.format

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to be able to access a key in a dictionary that has a dot with `str.format()`. How can I do that?

For example format for a key without a dot works:

```
>>> "{hello}".format(**{ 'hello' : '2' })
'2'
```

But it doesn't when the key has a dot in it:

```
>>> "{hello.world}".format(**{ 'hello.world' : '2' })
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'hello'
```

Comment: You cannot have periods or semicolons in _variable_ names.

Comment: Your variable name *has no semicolon*. It has a period.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a dot in Python format strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035168/how-to-use-a-dot-in-python-format-strings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot. The [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) supports *only* integers or *valid Python identifiers* as keys. From the documentation:

> ```
> arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
> ```

where `identifier` is [defined as](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier):

> Identifiers (also referred to as names) are described by the following lexical definitions:
>
> ```
> identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
> ```

No dots (or semicolons) allowed.

You could use your dictionary as a *second level* object:

```
"{v[hello.world]}".format(v={ 'hello.world' : '2' })
```

Here we assigned the dictionary to the name `v`, then index into it using a key name. These can be any string, not just identifiers.